# XCODE: collision between left part of an image and another image

Tags: xcode, collision-detection, move, uitouch, cgrect

I´m developing a game in which the player moves a toothbrush along the screen (dragging it). I want it to react when the left side of the toothbrush(the part of the toothpaste) touches another image(teeth) to "clean it". I've tried the next code but i dont get the best result,because the teeth reacts with the hole image of the toothbrush, even with the handle. I think the problem is the ".center"command. After searching in internet, i havent seen anything.
I would really appreciate your help.

```
@synthesize toothbrush, teeth;

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *myTouch =[[event allTouches]anyObject];
toothbrush.center=[myTouch locationInView:self.view];
[self collision];
}

-(void)collision {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(toothbrush.frame, teeth.frame)) {
    cont++; //when the two images collide, the "cont" variable increases its value 
    mensaje.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",cont];
}
```

Comment: Why arent you using 2D-bitmask to get rid of space-brushing or handle-brushing?

Comment: What do you mean with 2D bitmask? it´s posible to do it in IOS?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableBitVectorRef/Reference/reference.html has some info about it anyway, i am noob

Comment: Thank you all! Finally we got it!